# Copy values from one sheet to another without including pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working copy and paste scripts, but they copy and paste the pictures.  I am fairly sure it does this because the pictures are linked to the cells to size and move.  What I would like to do is still copy the cells (their values), but without the pictures that are linked to the cells.  This also needs to work on Windows as well as OS X.

## Copy Script

```
Dim Section As Long, NextRow As Long
Dim FATPMetiPath As String, FATPMetiFolderPath As String

Sheets("Results").Activate
Range("Results").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("Results").ClearContents

For Section = 1 To 8 '32

    NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next empty row

    Sheets("Function Test Procedure").Select

    Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("A:N").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & NextRow)

Next Section
```

## Paste Script

```
    Set rngCopy = wsFTP.Range("FTPResults1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rngCopyNotes = wsFTP.Range("FTPResults2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rngCopyFRResults = wsFTP.Range("FTPResults3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rngCopyFRResults2 = wsFTP.Range("FTPResults4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    NextRow = wsFail.Range("Fail_Report_Table").Cells(1, 1).Row
    rngCopy.Copy wsFail.Range("A" & NextRow)
    rngCopyNotes.Copy wsFail.Range("H" & NextRow)
    rngCopyFRResults.Copy wsFail.Range("C" & NextRow)
    rngCopyFRResults2.Copy wsFail.Range("D" & NextRow)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For Copy Script

Change `Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("A:N").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & NextRow)`

To:

```
Dim TotalRows As Long
TotalRows = Range("FTPSec" & Section).Rows.Count
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & NextRow).Resize(TotalRows,14).Value = Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("A:N").Value
```

### For Paste Script

Write this (to replace the last 4 lines in your code):

```
wsFail.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = rngCopy.Value
wsFail.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = rngCopyNotes.Value
wsFail.Range("C" & NextRow).Value = rngCopyFRResults.Value
wsFail.Range("D" & NextRow).Value = rngCopyFRResults2.Value
```

Comment: It does not copy the pictures anymore, but it does not copy the values either.  It returns the Section headers in column A of the source sheet, but not the actual results.  it returns 8 values instead of 157 values.

Comment: It copies all of the Item Numbers from each section, but does not copy any of the other information contained in each of those named ranges (sections).

Comment: added the column count to the `Resize` method (based on `A:N` ... sorry, forgot about that :( ... see edited answer.

Comment: How would I modify the copy script to keep the formatting (Bold text, horizontally and vertically centered values, and borders)?

Comment: @Gerasimos.Zap -  you can try `Copy` Then `PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`. If that doesn't work, please post that as a separate question, since it is.